# Checking if a list of numbers are divisible by the two inputs?

Tags: java, eclipse, numbers

I'm writing a  program where you input two divisors and a list of numbers you want to check are divisible by the two numbers you inputed.

Here's an example of how the output should look like:

```
Please input a command: A
 A [Create a new divisible test] 
 [Type two divisors]: 2 6
 [Input a list of numbers in one single line]: 2 4 6 9 15 18 19 25 30


Please input a command: D
 D [Display the information]
  ( 2 4 6 9 15 18 19 25 30 ) are numbers to check
  ( 2 4 6 18 30 ):   are divisible by 2
  ( 6 18 30 ):  are divisible by 6
  ( 6 18 30  ): are divisible by both 2 and 6
```

My problem is it won't check which number is divisible by the two divisors, instead it prints out

```
  ( 2 4 6 9 15 18 19 25 30 ) are numbers to check
  ( 2 4 6 9 15 18 19 25 30  ):   are divisible by 2
  ( 2 4 6 9 15 18 19 25 30  ):  are divisible by 6
  ( 2 4 6 9 15 18 19 25 30   ): are divisible by both 2 and 6.
```

here's my code:

```
class Divisible {
    private int divisor1;
    private int divisor2;
    public String numbers;

    public Divisible() {
        divisor1 = (Integer) null;
        divisor2 = (Integer) null;
        numbers = " ";
    }

    public Divisible(int div1, int div2, String num) {
        this.divisor1 = div1;

        this.divisor2 = div2;

        this.numbers = num;
    }


    private boolean isDivisible1(int input) {
        boolean isDivisible1 = true;

        return (input % divisor1 == 0);
    }

    private boolean isDivisible2(int input) {

        boolean isDivisible2 = true;

        return (input % divisor2 == 0);
    }

    public String printDivisible1() {

        if (this.isDivisible1(divisor1)) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("are divisible by " + divisor1);
        }
        return numbers;
    }

    public String printDivisible2() {

        if (this.isDivisible2(divisor2)) {
            System.out.println(" are divisible by " + divisor2);
        }
        return numbers;
    }

    public String printDivisibleBoth() {
        if (this.isDivisible1(divisor1) && this.isDivisible2(divisor2))
            System.out.println(" are  divisible by " + divisor1 + " and " + divisor2);
        return numbers;
    }
}
```

Comment: `divisor1 = (Integer) null;` will never work because `Ìnteger` can't unbox `null`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're missing a few steps in your code!

To solve this problem we need to:

1. Break the string of numbers up, and convert them into integers, and enter them into a list or array.
2. Iterate over this list when printing, applying your `isDivisible()` function to determine if it should go to output.

First I think maybe we could make your program a bit more modular. In particular your `isDivisible(int input)` functions could be changed to something like:

```
private boolean isDivisible(int input, int divisor) {
    return (input%divisor==0);
}
```

this means we can use the same function for both our divisors! Like `isDivisble(30, 6)` and `isDivisble(30, 2)`

Now we need to focus on your string of numbers to check. You'll notice our new function requires an integer for the input, but we currently have a huge string containing all our numbers. We could probably try a function like:

```
String[] numArray = num.split(" ");
```

to take our String 'num' and split it up into pieces wherever there is a space (" "), and put those pieces into the elements of the 'numArray' array.

Ok, now we have our array of inputs. All that's left is to convert these elements into Integers so they can be used as inputs to our `isDivisible()` function. We can use the `Integer.valueOf(str s)` function to do this!

And that's all the tools we need to finish this problem! Put together, a rough solution would look like:

```
String[] numArray = num.split(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++) {
    if (isDivisible(Integer.valueOf(numArray[i]), div1)) {
        System.out.print(numArray[i] + " ");
    }
}
System.out.println("):   are divisible by " + div1);
```

UPDATE

No arrays!? Ok, in that case I think your teacher wants you to iterate through the input, checking if they are divisible, and if they are, concatenating some output strings.

So let's start by adding a couple of Strings that will later become our output to the top of our code:

```
class Divisible {
    private String outputDiv1 = "( ";
    private String outputDiv2 = "( ";
    private String outputBoth = "( ";
```

Now, for each of these outputs we want to concatenate only the divisible numbers. We can do this without arrays by looping through the characters of our String num, and breaking apart the numbers whenever we find spaces like:

```
//Since we're checking for spaces, we should probably add one to the end of our string, so we can find the last number!
num += " ";    
//We need to keep a record of the previous space!
int lastSpace = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
    if (num.charAt(i) == ' ') {
        //If the current character is a space, we know everything before it and the last space was a number

        //Our logic will go here!
        //Currently converts our string into an Integer and prints it out
        int currentNumber = Integer.parseInt(num.substring(lastSpace, i));
        System.out.println(currentNumber);

        //Update where the last space we found was
        //The '+ 1' is so we skip the spaces!
        lastSpace = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Ok, no we are iterating through our string and breaking them apart without using any arrays! All that's left to do is apply the tool we made earlier `isDivisible()`.

Something like:

```
if (isDivisible(currentNum, div1)) {
     outputDiv1 += currentNum;
}
```

Can be put into `//Our logic goes here` section to determine whether a number should be added to our output list or not!

Finally, we print off our finished lists:

```
System.out.println(outputDiv1 + " ): are divisble by " + div1);
```

Comment: hi, I did the changes for the second  part like you suggested, but for the first part when converting the string to an int I'm not allowed to use any arrays. I tried using Integer.parseInt() instead but it gives me an  exception. Any suggestions ?

Comment: All updated w/o using arrays! Sorry for the delay. If you still get exceptions after updating, post them here and we'll figure them out.